# get the Previous modal view controller

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have 4 view controllers: VC1,VC2,VC3,VC4.

VC4 can be called from VC1,VC2,VC3, my point is how to get which one of view controller (VC1,VC2,VC3) has called VC4?

Answer (score 3):

Flohei's answer is right, but a bit long winded given there's already a method to do this in iOS. There's no real need to add another property. You can use the `parentViewController` property to find out which view controller is currently displaying your modal controller.

Comment: parentViewController was removed by Apple

Answer (score 1):

You could add a UIViewController property to VC4 and set this one every time you create a VC4 instance to the current viewController.